# React Native, Adding Image Beside FlatList item

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, url

This is simple code has built with React Native and it works fine, it gets Data from JSON link and show it in FlatList as Text Item. I want to add image foreach Item inside this FlatList. I don't know in which part in this code will make the image to be displayed.
This is the JSON file:

```
[
  {"uid":"001","uname":"Jon","uimage":"http:\/\/me.com\/jon.jpg"},
  {"uid":"002","uname":"Eds","uimage":"http:\/\/me.com\/eds.jpg"},
  {"uid":"003","uname":"Sam","uimage":"http:\/\/me.com\/sam.jpg"}
]
```

This is the RN code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// import all the components we are going to use
import {
SafeAreaView,
Text,
StyleSheet,
View,
FlatList,
Image
} from 'react-native';
const App = () => {
const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://www.link2json.com/data.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            setMasterDataSource(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}, []);

const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        // Flat List Item
        <Text
            style={styles.itemStyle}
            onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
            {item.unam}
        </Text>           
        <Image source={ uri: {'uimage'}} /> //<--Here's the issue
    );
};

const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
        // Flat List Item Separator
        <View
            style={{
                height: 0.5,
                width: '100%',
                backgroundColor: '#C8C8C8',
            }}
        />
    );
};

const getItem = (item) => {
    // Function for click on an item
    alert('Id : ' + item.uid + ' Title : ' + item.unam);

};

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={masterDataSource}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
                renderItem={ItemView}
            />
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
},
itemStyle: {
    padding: 10,
},
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like below

```
const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        // Flat List Item
       <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <Text
            style={styles.itemStyle}
            onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
            {item.unam}
        </Text>           
        <Image style={{height:50,width:50}} source={{uri: item.uimage}} />
       </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: your suggested code does not throw errors, but it doesn't show the images next the Flatlist items.

Comment: @HowardJohn can you access the uimage url in browser and see the image ?

Comment: Yes its, even I used this image link to make sure : https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png

Comment: i tested and it works fine, you added the styles above right ?

Comment: @HowardJohn check this snack https://snack.expo.io/8rjt_7MS7

Comment: it works if the JSON file has full path for the image. what if I want to put a varaible inside the image link like this:  <Image source={{ uri: 'http://me.com/' + item.unam + '.png' }} /> and use this link inside FlatList (renderItem) how to do it?

Comment: If its a valid url it will work as expected, but if you are going to require a local resource you will have to do it in a different way

Comment: I misspelling (name) so even with (uname) doesn't work. jpg -> png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224710/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-howardjohn).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with last answer but did few styling. actually you can't return 2 view item so you need to add a parent view to use other items in it and by this you are only returning single view item.

```
const ItemView = ({ item }) => {
    return (
       <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
        <Text
            style={styles.itemStyle}
            onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
            {item.unam}
        </Text>           
        <Image style={{height:50,width:50}} source={{uri: item.uimage}} />
       </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: no more errors, but there're no images beside items.

Comment: Can you add a prototype image to your question how you want to show your image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Image style={{height:50,width:50}} source={{uri: item.uimage}} /> // add here
```